# Remove current element based on data availability in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a method which updates the `fill` styles based on supplied data for a bunch of circles drawn in `d3`:

```
function updateFill(data) {
    nodes.style("fill", function(d) {
        var latest = data[d.id];
        if (latest === 1) {
            return "#000000";
        } else if (latest === 2) {
            return "#ffffff";
        } else if (latest === 3) {
            return "#d3d3d3";
        } else {
            // no data available, remove the current element/circle
        }
    }
}
```

My question is that, can I simply do `this.remove()` inside the final `else` clause (without returning anything) to remove the circle off the `d3` graph? Or, do I need to first set a color for a circle, and then use some selection to remove it after `nodes.style(...)`, e.g. `nodes.filter(function() {
    return this.style.fill == '#someColor';
}).data([]).exit().remove();`?

What is the proper way here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really the D3 way to handle data, but in principle there's no problem removing elements like this. That is, you should be able to run `d3.select(this).remove()` from the function you've posted.

I would however advise to refactor the code such that the elements to be removed can be identified using the usual enter/update/exit pattern.